# Proving Pigeonhole Principle is Unsatisfiable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, pigeonhole-principle, satisfiability

Consider the resolution rule, that is, I can add a resolvent of
any two clauses to the formula.

***My question is:*** From using only this above rule how to show that the pigeon-hole formula for 3 pigeons and 2 holes is unsatisfiable?

Comment: In item 6, what is "hole 3"?

Comment: Also, I don't see any clause saying the pigeons 1 and 3 can't be n the same hole.

Comment: @AndreasBlass you are right, so how to approach? Any hints.

Comment: How to approach: First make sure you have the right assumptions. In particular, there are only two holes. (Meanwhile I noticed the "hole 3" error earlier in your list.) You have the right general idea for expressing "each pigeon is in a hole" and "no two pigeons are in the same hole", but you need to make sure you formulate these for all the pigeons, all pairs of pigeons, and only 2 holes. Once you correct the assumptions, they'll be contradictory and so the resolution argument should work. (Some people add clauses saying "no pigeon is in two holes" but those clauses aren't actually needed.)

Comment: Previously, I didn't read past the incorrect assumptions, but now I see that you've applied the resolution rule incorrectly in line 10. To apply resolution to two clauses, you need a variable to occur with negation in one and without negation in the other. There seem to be similar errors in Step 3. So review the resolution rule.  Finally, the two formulas in your Step 4 are not contradictory.

Comment: @AndreasBlass please check my answer and let me know if I did any mistake.

Comment: Not sure this will help, but here is a non-numeric version of the PHP:  Suppose  $h:  P \to H$, and there exists no surjective function mapping $H$ onto $P$ (i.e. more pigeons than holes), then there exists $x, y \in P$ such that  $x\neq y$ and $h(x)=h(y)$. Formal proof using a form of natural deduction: https://dcproof.com/PigeonholePrinciple.htm (29 lines)

Comment: @DanChristensen would you please answer this question by your mentioned version of PHP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To show that the pigeon-hole formula for 3 pigeons and 2 holes is unsatisfiable using the resolution rule, you can create clauses representing the conditions and then derive a contradiction.

Let $P(i, h)$ represent "Pigeon $i$ is in Hole $h$. The pigeon-hole formula constraints are:

1. each pigeon is in at least one hole.
2. no hole contains more than one pigeon.

Now, create the formulas:

1. For each pigeon, there must be a hole they are in:
   $(P(1, 1) ∨ P(1, 2)) ∧ (P(2, 1) ∨ P(2, 2)) ∧ (P(3, 1) ∨ P(3, 2))$
2. no hole contains more than one pigeon:
   $(\neg P(1,1)\lor\neg P(2,1))\land$
   $(\neg P(1,2)\lor\neg P(2,2))\land$
   $(\neg P(1,1)\lor\neg P(3,1))\land$
   $(\neg P(1,2)\lor\neg P(3,2))\land$
   $(\neg P(2,1)\lor\neg P(3,1))\land$
   $(\neg P(2,2)\lor\neg P(3,2))$

Now, apply the resolution rule between all the causes above of formulas (1) and(2),I obtain an empty clause, $\phi$ (representing a contradiction). If you reach an empty clause, it implies that the initial set of clauses is unsatisfiable.

Comment: Your two constraints have reversed the roles of pigeons and holes. Constraint 1 should be "each pigeon is in at least one hole" and constraint 2 should be "no hole contains more than one pigeon."

Comment: @AndreasBlass please check now, everything is okay?

Comment: @AndreasBlass I have asked one [Question here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/462890/how-can-one-build-a-min-2-wise-independent-small-sample-space-from-min-3-wise-pe), I have no clue to solve, would you help me to solve.

Comment: The best  help I can give is to tell you to review the relevant definitions ("clause", "resolution rule", "resolution proof") and make sure your work agrees with them. But I'll give some additional hints here.  (1) Where you wrote "Now create the clauses", you've written two formulas that are not clauses; #1 is a conjunction of 3 clauses and #2 is even farther from being a clause. (2) Your formula #2 expresses "no pigeon is in two holes", which is not what you intended. (3) "which can be simplified" is not allowed in a resolution proof; only the resolution rule can be used.

Comment: I'd write #2 as six clauses, one of which would be $\neg P(2,2)\lor\neg P(3,2), expressing that pigeons 2 and 3 can't both be in hole 2. The other five clauses for #2 are similar, dealing with each hole and each pair of pigeons.

Comment: @AndreasBlass Would you help this proposition logic question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852799/application-of-blocked-clauses

Answer (score 0):

As requested (IIUC):

Not sure if this will help, but here is a non-numeric version of the PHP:

Suppose h: P → H (for non-empty P) and there exists no surjective function mapping H onto P (i.e. more pigeons than holes), then there exists x, y ∈ P such that x≠y and h(x)=h(y) (i.e. distinct pigeons x and y are in the same hole).

Formal proof (29 lines) available on request. Includes link to lemma (381 lines).

Comment: Would you help this proposition logic question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4852799/application-of-blocked-clauses